# Как сделать много одинаковых Swiper слайдеров?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Есть вот такой блок.

Если в основном слайдере много слайдов, внутри которых свои thumbs swiper слайдеры то внутренние thumbs слайдеры имеют один и тот-же класс по которому они инициализируются и тупо не работают, потому что у них классы повторяются по которым идёт инициализация.

В общем как сделать такую конструкцию из swiper слайдеров?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в смысле на одной странице много слайдеров ?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant есть основной слайдер, у которого слайды состоят из слайцдера и текста справа. У основного слайдера много таких слайдов в которых есть свой слайдер и текст. Как сделать такую конструкцию чтоб это всё работало на swiper слайдере

Comment: разве не похож пример https://swiperjs.com/demos там где thumbs gallery ?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant у каждого слайда в основном слайдере, есть своя thumbs галерея. И получается что у этих thumbs галерей одни и те же классы по которым инициализируются.

Comment: https://codepen.io/qamos/pen/ExEYwYm типо как тут. Если добавить 2 одинаковых галереи то они не работают нормально

Comment: А как вы инициализируете эти слайдеры?

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st codepen.io/qamos/pen/ExEYwYm  вот пример. Как добавить множество слайдеров галерей, с одинаковыми классами, не конфликтуя друг с другом

Answer (score 0):

Код ниже проинициализирует (должен) все ваши слайдеры в слайдере

```
let swiperThumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-thumbs"); //Нашли все слайдеры, которые в слайдере

swiperThumbs.forEach(
    let swiper = new Swiper(value, {
        //Указываете параметры инициализации (direction, loop и т.д.). И, помнится, обязательно нужно добавить следующие два параметра
        observer: true,
        observerParents: true
    });
);
```

Comment: Вообще не об этом речь..

Comment: @De.Minov, жаль, очень жаль. Надо бы рекомендовать ответ к удалению...